# Can't get Sass to work with @snowpack/app-template-react-typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sass, snowpack

*I'm trying to get Sass to work with [@snowpack/app-template-react-typescript](https://github.com/snowpackjs/snowpack/tree/main/create-snowpack-app/app-template-react-typescript)* 
I followed [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@snowpack/plugin-sass). I've tried making a new project and adding it but still nothing works :(

**snowpack.config.js**

```js
/** @type {import("snowpack").SnowpackUserConfig } */
module.exports = {
  mount: {
    public: '/',
    src: '/_dist_',
  },
  plugins: [
    '@snowpack/plugin-react-refresh',
    '@snowpack/plugin-dotenv',
    '@snowpack/plugin-typescript',
    '@snowpack/plugin-sass',
  ],
  install: [
    /* ... */
  ],
  installOptions: {
    /* ... */
  },
  devOptions: {
    /* ... */
  },
  buildOptions: {
    /* ... */
  },
  proxy: {
    /* ... */
  },
  alias: {
    /* ... */
  },
};
```

If you need any more info ask me in the comments ⬇ 
Thanks!

Comment: What exactly don't work? Please share error message

Comment: I cahnge all filenames and everything but when I load it on browser there's no styling.

Comment: and there is no error message it's just that styles aren't loading here are the verbose logs
https://gist.github.com/UnlockDep/492a0ef779b6ba80df3d8efedc3e106c

Comment: If you share reproducable example in github, your chances to get the answer will increase

Comment: You can reproduce it by doing the following:
`npx create-snowpack-app reproduction --template @snowpack/app-template-react-typescript && cd reproduction  && npm i -D @snowpack/plugin-sass`
then head to the `snowpack.config.js` and in the plugins add `"@snowpack/plugin-sass"` and convert your css files to scss and then if you run it there will be no styling (thats the issue). But I'll still make a repo with all the info.

Comment: Wait I Just made another project for the repo and now it works!
Why isn't it working in my other project?

Comment: This is the main question in programming :D

Comment: Never mind it turns out that it just didn't load .

Comment: Still same issue

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add the rollup plugin to get scss working:

```
module.exports = {
  mount: {
    public: '/',
    src: '/_dist_',
  },
  plugins: [
    '@snowpack/plugin-react-refresh',
    '@snowpack/plugin-dotenv',
    '@snowpack/plugin-typescript',
    '@snowpack/plugin-sass',
  ],
  install: [
    /* ... */
  ],
  installOptions: {
    /* ... */
  },
  devOptions: {
    /* ... */
  },
  buildOptions: {
    /* ... */
  },
  proxy: {
    /* ... */
  },
  alias: {
    /* ... */
  },
  packageOptions: {        /* <------- add these values to your config */
    rollup: {
        require('rollup-plugin-scss')(),
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: I think the packageOptions.rollup object is missing another nested 'plugins' array property, in which the rollup plugin scss instance should live: packageOptions: {
    rollup: {
      plugins: [require('rollup-plugin-scss')()],
    },
  }